# Resize table header when using dynamic types

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I have a `TableViewController` with a header. 
This header is a container, which links to another storyboard named `Header.storyboard`

[image: TableViewController]

`Header.storyboard` contains a stack view with some labels, that are dynamically typed.

Labels text comes from DB.

No regards to the text dimension or size I want to visualise it correctly.

[image]

I've used some answers from SO to get the header correctly resize, but without luck:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableHeaderView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        // Dynamic sizing for the header view
        if let headerView = tableHeaderView {
            headerView.setNeedsLayout()
            headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

            let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
            var headerFrame = headerView.frame

            // If we don't have this check, viewDidLayoutSubviews() will get
            // repeatedly, causing the app to hang.
            if height != headerFrame.size.height {
                headerFrame.size.height = height
                headerView.frame = headerFrame
                tableHeaderView = headerView
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: have you tried func tableView(UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection: Int) in UITableViewDelegate?

Comment: Do you mean it is using Dynamic Type as the Apple Technology (e.g. UIFontTextStyle) or you mean that they just have different font sizes?

Comment: @Alistra, I mean Dynamic Type as Apple defines it - UIFontTextStyle used in `storyboard`. When app is running I want to change fonts from accessibility, and the height of tableHeader I want to change accordingly, so that text to be visible

Comment: Did you try to listen to `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification` and `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` on the header then?

Comment: From this one https://useyourloaf.com/blog/auto-adjusting-fonts-for-dynamic-type/, I've understood that "Setting adjustsFontsForContentSizeCategory to true causes the font to update automatically when the user changes the text content size. You no longer need to observe the content size category did change notification.". I don't know where to call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize`

Comment: Sort of a hack, but since the user has to close your app to change accessibility settings you could just call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` on your headerview in `viewWillAppear`. That way it'll be called and the header will resize correctly when the user re-opens the app from settings.

Comment: @LauraCalinoiu Did you find a solution?

Comment: @LeeviGraham, no. I didn't manage. I've set up a static font - not a dynamic type :(.

Answer (score 4):

Table view header can be automatically resized

but with containers it likely will not work

use custom view instead for viewForHeaderInSection

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 10
        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let lab = UILabel()
        lab.text = "text \(section)"
        lab.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10 * CGFloat(section) + 1)
        return lab
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    //this method overriding is not necessary
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I can not remove containers since it's legacy code.

Comment: `viewDidLayoutSubviews` from my code actually resizes container automatically, but it seems that it does not care that font was changed.

Comment: autoLayout autoheigh works very bad with containers, embedded viewControllers and other simular stuff. The only way i see: calculate heigh programmatically via systemLayoutSizeFitting and pass it with heightForHeaderInSection

Comment: `systemLayoutSizeFitting`, does not care about font size. It gives me all the time same size.

Comment: you can try getting real size of view, after it renders on screen, then set its heigh  with heightForHeaderInSection

Answer (score 3):

First, instead of giving the height to the view, you should give the label a height

```
class ViewController : UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Baran"

    return cell

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return heightForView()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.heightForView()))
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    let label : UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.heightForView()))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    label.text = "Size To Fit Tutorial"
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 50)
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    headerView.addSubview(label)

    return headerView
}

//Self Sizing height ....
func heightForLabel(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byCharWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height
}

func heightForView() -> CGFloat{

    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width

    let text = "Size To Fit Tutorial"
    let font : UIFont!
    switch UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom {
    case .pad:
        font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 35)
    case .phone:
        font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 50)
    default:
        font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 24)
    }
    let height = heightForLabel(text: text, font: font, width: screenWidth)

    return height
}
}
```

[image]

**Hope this helps**

Comment: it is not what I want. I want to quit app, and change fonts from settings, and I need the header to be automatically resized, so that when a bigger font it is used, this should be visible. Also, I can not change so much in the code, like you suggested, because I work on legacy code. Also, my header is inside a container, which I do not want to change due to big logic there. Thanks for asking and answering

Answer (score 2):

try to implement

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int)
```

and

`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int)`
your code should look like this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return tableHeaderView.bounds.size.height
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return tableHeaderView
}
```

Comment: No, it does not work. :( What I want is the automatic resize of header when font is changed from accessibility.

Answer (score -1):

For Xcode 11, iOS 13 - I just had to tick these two boxes in Interface Builder:

[image: Interface Builder]

Comment: Header for the sectionView is no't the same as tableHeaderView property inside tableView